# convert classification models output to score

Tags: classification

I have two classification models: The first model classifies driving behaviors to normal and aggressive; the output looks like this `[0.91,0.09]`. the second model classifies driving patterns to (speed-up, slow-down, Turn, steady), the output looks like this `[0.42,0.38, 0.15, 0.05]`. I want to use these outputs to give the driver a score (0 to 10) over a period of time (for example 20 minutes), knowing that the classification is done every 60 second (each 60 seconds have a pair of classes, ex `(Aggressive, Turn)`). is there any algorithm to do this?

I tried to use fuzzy logic expert system, but the output can't be fuzzified. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a formula to take your inputs that calculates a driver score. That formula will look like whatever you want it to because you are the one defining what makes a high and low driver score.

Start by thinking what makes a good driving score and what makes a bad driving score. Which variables correspond to that and how do the other variables change those. There is no standard formula. You are the one defining what it means.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Think simple, do you have a dataset with driving scores? If you do you can use supervised learning algorithms. If you don't, and there is no good way to create a dataset for such a large input-output space, maybe think out of the box.

You can create a simulation environment and go with reinforcement learning algorithms, then you can train both models with the reward functions from the environment.